Elasticsearch multiple query results are inconsistent
When I use the following syntax:
{ "track_total_hits": true, "query": { "match_all": {} } }
When I query (I use match_all to get an accurate total number of docs to troubleshoot this problem), each time I get
{ "total": { "value": 222, "relation": "eq" }
The value will change. In fact, there are 10,000 data in my index, but occasionally a total value of less than 10,000 will be returned.
Elasticsearch version: 7.17.1
Cpu architecture: ARM64
Note: Each of my nodes has 256g of memory and 64c cores, and using /nodes/stats did not find any abnormalities in the datanode node, of course, this also includes logs on the operating system and gc logs.
Already read this article: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/consistent-scoring.html#_scores_are_not_reproducible
Troubleshooting process:
1.My cluster consists of 3 master_nodes and 6 data_nodes. This index has 9 primary shards and 1 replica shard.
2.I use the combination of /_cat/shards and preference=_shards:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 to troubleshoot. At present, I have found a very clear conclusion: when I use preference=_shards:0,1,3,4,6,7, the total value is always constant, and the three shards 2,5,8 are all allocated to one of the fixed datanode nodes (The same is true for other problematic indexes), but the results of /_cat/shards are all STARTED, and /_cluster/health is also GREEN

I still don't understand the relationship between this phenomenon and score, because it seems that my application scenario does not care much about the score value. I just use it to store request records and use the exact id to match the doc. But I found this problem when the web page displayed all the data. The total number of request records obtained each time was inconsistent, which caused my paging display to be abnormal.
